# Action listener/Throws IOException Conflict

Tags: java, actionlistener, ioexception

I am attempting to make a GUI for a program that reads and writes information from a random access file and display it at will. I cannot manipulate anything but the GUI and must refer to prebuilt methods( if the methods truly are unusable then I can make an exception).

The Part I am having issues with is dealing with an IOException while writing to a file.

```
public static class  EdtButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
    {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm")) //if the confirm button is pressed
            {

                    writeAll(); //runs all write methods using the strings from the text field

                frameAddMovie.setVisible(false);
            }
```

The writeAll refers to a series of methods that write from a file based on the string it is passed, these strings come from textfields on my GUI Window. They all look something like this;

```
public static void writeDirector(int recordNum, String directorIn)throws IOException
    {
        int position;
        RandomAccessFile recordFile = new RandomAccessFile("RecordFile", "rw");
        position = recSize * (recordNum-1)+32; // read 32 spaces into the record to the start of the director line
        recordFile.seek(position);
        recordFile.writeBytes(directorIn);

    }
```

At the point were the Confirm button is pressed and writeAll() is run there is an IOException thrown that cannot be caught with the method or the Class.

Comment: Can you give the full exception like `IOException  File Not found` or any other?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm")) //if the confirm button is pressed
```

wouldn't you want that to be

`if (e.getSource() = buttonname)`